# How to take substring of a given string until the first appearance of specified character?

Tags: string, perl, substring

The question is for perl.

For example if I have `"hello.world"` and the specified character is `'.'` then the result I want is `"hello"`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

See [`perldoc -f index`](http://p3rl.org/index):

```
$x = "hello.world";
$y = substr($x, 0, index($x, '.'));
```

Comment: I didn't mean the perldoc reference as an "RTFM" but as a "For more information, see: ____".  :)

Answer (score 7):

Using [`substr`](http://p3rl.org/substr):

```
my $string = "hello.world";
my $substring = substr($string, 0, index($string, "."));
```

Or using regexp:

```
my ($substring2) = $string =~ /(.*)?\./;
```

Comment: The substr will give the string up until the *first* period `.`, the regex will give the string up until the *last* period. Note the difference. Use `.*?` for non-greedy regex to get the same functionality.

Answer (score 2):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "hello.world";
my $dot = index($string, '.');
my $word = substr($string, 0, $dot);

print "$word\n";
```

gives you `hello`

Comment: for WORLD;    my $world= substr($string ,$dot,length($string ));

Answer (score 2):

In the spirit of TIMTOWTDI, and introducing new features: Using the [non-destructive option](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) `/r`

```
my $partial = $string =~ s/\..*//sr;
```

The greedy `.*` end will chop off everything after the first period, including possible newline characters (`/s` option), but keep the original string intact and remove the need for parens to impose list context (`/r` option).

Quote from perlop:

> If the /r (non-destructive) option is used then it runs the
>   substitution on a copy of the string and instead of returning the
>   number of substitutions, it returns the copy whether or not a
>   substitution occurred. The original string is never changed when /r is
>   used. The copy will always be a plain string, even if the input is an
>   object or a tied variable.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
my $string = 'hello.world';
print ((split /\./, $string)[0], "\n");
```