# EXtracting sub-string in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string in a variable:

```
$mystr = "some text %PARTS/dir1/dir2/myfile.abc some more text";
```

Now %PARTS is literally present in the string, it is not a variable or hash.
I want to extract the sub-string `%PARTS/dir1/dir2/myfile.abc` from it. I created the following reg expression. I am just a beginner in Perl. So please let me know if I have done anything wrong.

```
my $local_file = substr ($mystr, index($mystr, '%PARTS'), index($mystr, /.*%PARTS ?/));
```

I even tried this:

```
my $local_file = substr ($mystr, index($mystr, '%PARTS'), index($mystr, /.*%PARTS' '?/));
```

But both give nothing if I print `$local_file`.
What might be wrong here?
Thank You.

**UPDATE:** Referred the following sites for using this method:

1. http://perlmeme.org/howtos/perlfunc/substr.html see example 1c
2. [How to take substring of a given string until the first appearance of specified character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256382/how-to-take-substring-of-a-given-string-until-the-first-appearance-of-specified)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `index` function returns the first index of the occurrence of a substring in a string, else `-1`. It has nothing to do with regular expressions.

Regular expressions are applied to a string with the *bind operator* `=~`.

To extract the matched area of a regular expression, enclose the pattern in parens (a *capture group*). The matched substring will then be available in `$1`:

```
my $str = "some text %PARTS/dir1/dir2/myfile.abc some more text";
if ($str =~ /(%PARTS\S+)/) {
  my $local_file = $1;
  ...; # do something
} else {
  die "the match failed"; # do something else
}
```

The `\S` character class will match every non-space character.

To learn about regular expressions, you can look at the [`perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

Comment: @stema: You cannot directly assign the matched part without using a capturing group. You can avoid the group if you use `$&`, or you can avoid the `$1` if you use the group or list context plus `/g`.

Comment: bad example.  you aren't checking if the regex failed, which could leave $1 set from some other regex execution.  the easiest way to do this is as shown in dolmen's answer.

Answer (score 3):

The [`index`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) function is not related to regexps. Its arguments are just strings, not regexps. So your usage is wrong.

[Regexps](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) are a powerful feature of Perl and the most appropriate tool for this task:

```
my ($local_file) = $mystr =~ /(%PARTS[^ ]+)/;
```

See [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators) for more information on the `=~` operator.